# content type 'text/xml; charset=utf-8' was not the expected type 'application/soap+xml; charset=utf-8'

Tags: php, soap

I've been trying for a long time to send right request to soap server. I'm keep getting error message.

Here is my xml

GET LAST REQUEST (newlines added):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:ns1="http://tempuri.org/">
<SOAP-ENV:Body><ns1:TestData1><ns1:iVal>1</ns1:iVal></ns1:TestData1></SOAP-ENV:Body>
</SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
```

GET LAST RESPONSE :

REQUEST HEADERS:

```
POST /DPWebService/CardsService.svc/ICardsService HTTP/1.1
Host: d67v7tg1
Connection: Keep-Alive
User-Agent: PHP-SOAP/5.2.9-1
Content-Type: text/xml; charset=utf-8
SOAPAction: "http://tempuri.org/ICardsService/TestData1"
Content-Length: 254
```

Here is the response.

```
object(SoapFault)#2 (8) { 
["message:protected"]=> string(142) "Cannot process the message because the content type 'text/xml; charset=utf-8' was not the expected type 'application/soap+xml; charset=utf-8'." 
["string:private"]=> string(0) "" 
["code:protected"]=> int(0) 
["file:protected"]=> string(32) "C:\localhost\www\test5\index.php" 
["line:protected"]=> int(208) 
["trace:private"]=> array(3) { 
    [0]=> array(4) { 
        ["function"]=> string(11) "__doRequest" 
        ["class"]=> string(10) "SoapClient" 
        ["type"]=> string(2) "->" 
        ["args"]=> array(5) { 
            [0]=> string(254) " 1 " 
            [1]=> string(59) "http://d67v7tg1/DPWebService/CardsService.svc/ICardsService" 
            [2]=> string(42) "http://tempuri.org/ICardsService/TestData1" 
            [3]=> int(1) 
            [4]=> int(0) 
        }
    } 
    [1]=> array(4) { 
        ["function"]=> string(6) "__call" 
        ["class"]=> string(10) "SoapClient" 
        ["type"]=> string(2) "->" 
        ["args"]=> array(2) { 
            [0]=> string(9) "TestData1" 
            [1]=> array(1) { 
                [0]=> array(2) { 
                    ["iVal"]=> int(1) 
                    ["strVal"]=> string(5) "Proba" 
                } 
            } 
        } 
    } 
    [2]=> array(6) { 
        ["file"]=> string(32) "C:\localhost\www\test5\index.php" 
        ["line"]=> int(208) 
        ["function"]=> string(9) "TestData1" 
        ["class"]=> string(10) "SoapClient" 
        ["type"]=> string(2) "->" 
        ["args"]=> array(1) { 
            [0]=> array(2) { 
                ["iVal"]=> int(1) 
                ["strVal"]=> string(5) "Proba" 
            } 
        } 
    } 
} 
["faultstring"]=> string(142) "Cannot process the message because the content type 'text/xml; charset=utf-8' was not the expected type 'application/soap+xml; charset=utf-8'." 
["faultcode"]=> string(4) "HTTP" 
}
```

GET LAST RESPONSE :

REQUEST HEADERS:

```
POST /DPWebService/CardsService.svc/ICardsService HTTP/1.1
Host: d67v7tg1
Connection: Keep-Alive
User-Agent: PHP-SOAP/5.2.9-1
Content-Type: text/xml; charset=utf-8
SOAPAction: "http://tempuri.org/ICardsService/TestData1"
Content-Length: 254
```

Answer (score 19):

PHP's native SOAP extension is an undebuggable binary blob of horrors.

[According to this comment in the PHP manual](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.soap.php#93888), it is hard-coded to send SOAP requests with the MIME content type `application/soap+xml`.

Your SOAP server seems to reject this content type, expecting only `text/xml`.

According to [this SOAP 1.2 standard document](http://www.w3.org/TR/soap12-part2/#soapinhttp), section 7.1.4 on SOAP over HTTP:

> Conforming implementations of this binding:
>
> 1. **MUST** be capable of sending and receiving messages serialized using media type "application/soap+xml" whose proper use and parameters are described in [A. The application/soap+xml Media Type](http://www.w3.org/TR/soap12-part2/#ietf-draft).

**The SOAP server you are using is not complaint with the 1.2 standard.**

(For the record, this is the first time I've ever, ever seen anyone with a question about the PHP SOAP extension where the problem *wasn't* with the extension itself!)

Comment: I have this problem in a WCF service which is called from PHP. Any idea how to tell IIS to become complaint with the 1.2 standard ?

Comment: `undebuggable binary blob of horrors.` +1 for that alone

Answer (score 19):

This appears to have fixed it for me.

```
$client = new SoapClient($this->url, array('soap_version' => SOAP_1_2));
```

Comment: Thanks, as @Charles mentioned below SOAP 1.2 supports 'text/xml'!

Answer (score 0):

On a sidenote ...

The "text/xml" mimetype determines the charset using the content of the message.
That means that it will read the first line of the XML message and look for a so-called "prolog". The prolog looks like this: `<?xml ... encoding="UTF-8?>`.

In RFC6657 it's described as follows:

> ... registrations for "text/*" media types that can transport charset information inside the corresponding payloads (such as "text/html" and "text/xml") SHOULD NOT specify the use of a "charset" parameter, nor any default value, in order to avoid conflicting interpretations should the "charset" parameter  value and the value specified in the payload disagree.

So, anyway, a mimetype like `"text/xml; charset=..."` is kind of dirty to start with. This mimetype should never declare a charset.