# how to implement ws-security using php to soap object

Tags: php, soap, ws-security

```
class WSSoapClient extends SoapClient {

    private $username;
    private $password;
    /*Generates de WSSecurity header*/
    private function wssecurity_header() {

        /* The timestamp. The computer must be on time or the server you are
         * connecting may reject the password digest for security.
         */
        $timestamp = gmdate('Y-m-d\TH:i:s\Z');
        /* A random word. The use of rand() may repeat the word if the server is
         * very loaded.
         */
        $nonce = mt_rand();
        /* This is the right way to create the password digest. Using the
         * password directly may work also, but it's not secure to transmit it
         * without encryption. And anyway, at least with axis+wss4j, the nonce
         * and timestamp are mandatory anyway.
         */
        $passdigest = base64_encode(
                pack('H*',
                        sha1(
                                pack('H*', $nonce) . pack('a*',$timestamp).
                                pack('a*',$this->password))));

       $auth='
<wsse:Security xmlns:wsse=\"http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd\">
<wsse:UsernameToken wsu:Id=\"UsernameToken-2\" xmlns:wsu=\"http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd\">
    <wsse:Username>'.$username.'</wsse:Username>
      <wsse:Password Type="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-username-token-profile-1.0#PasswordText">'.$password.'</wsse:Password>
    </wsse:UsernameToken>   
</wsse:Security>
<wsa:Action>http://www.kbb.com/2011/01/25/VehicleInformationService/IVehicleInformationService/GetYears</wsa:Action>
';

        /* XSD_ANYXML (or 147) is the code to add xml directly into a SoapVar.
         * Using other codes such as SOAP_ENC, it's really difficult to set the
         * correct namespace for the variables, so the axis server rejects the
         * xml.
         */
        $authvalues = new SoapVar($auth,XSD_ANYXML);
        $header = new SoapHeader("http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-".
            "200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd", "Security", $authvalues,
                true);

        return $header;
    }

    /* It's necessary to call it if you want to set a different user and
     * password
     */
    public function __setUsernameToken($username, $password) {
        $this->username = $username;
        $this->password = $password;
    }


    /* Overwrites the original method adding the security header. As you can
     * see, if you want to add more headers, the method needs to be modifyed
     */
    public function __soapCall($function_name, $arguments, $options=null,
            $input_headers=null, $output_headers=null) {

        $result = parent::__soapCall($function_name, $arguments, $options,
                $this->wssecurity_header());

        return $result;
    }
}
```

I am trying to use this but I am getting the following error:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught SoapFault exception: [HTTP] Cannot process the message because the content type 'text/xml; charset=utf-8' was not the expected type 'application/soap+xml; charset=utf-8'
```

Please tell me how can I set the content type using SOAP object.

Comment: Are you getting that error back from the server, or from your client script?

Comment: I am new to soap, please check this link https://www.go-stlucia.com/dav/soaptest16.php

Comment: Looks like the server is responding with a `Content-Type:` header that the PHP SOAP extension does not like. The PHP SOAP extension [is known to be somewhat bloody-minded](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5405874) in this respect, and there may be no solution to it using the native SOAP extension. You may need to roll you own SOAP client in order to get this to work (althought I'm sure there are alternatives out there) but we are getting somewhat beyond my comfort zone there. There are others here who are probably more qualified to answer this than I am.

Comment: There would be any way to set content type by soap object but i dont know how can i set the content type.

Answer (score 2):

If somebody needs answer for the same question, the answer is simple. You need to use SOAP version 1.2 to pass `Content-Type: application/soap+xml`

```
$soapClient = new SoapClient('http://example.com/wsdl.wsdl',array(
    'soap_version' => SOAP_1_2,
));
```

But, you must be careful, because it also adds `action: youraction` to `Content-Type`. For example:

```
Content-Type: application/soap+xml; charset=utf-8; action="http://example.com/path/to/your/action"
```