# Accessing WCF Soap Service Via Php

Tags: php, wcf

I am currently trying to learn how to make a WCF soap service. I am then trying to access this via PHP but I'm currently getting an error.

Below is the code to access the WCF soap service.

```
try
{
    $client = new SoapClient("http://localhost:8732/Design_Time_Addresses/SoapServer/Service1/?wsdl",
            array('soap_version'=>'SOAP_1_2', "trace" => 1, "exception" =>0));
    $result = $client->__soapCall("getData", array());

    echo "<pre>";
    print_r($result);
    echo "</pre>";
}
catch (Exception $e)
{
    echo $e->getMessage();
}
```

At the moment I'm currently getting the following error:

```
Cannot process the message because the content type 'text/xml; charset=utf-8' was not the expected type 'application/soap+xml; charset=utf-8'.
```

I've googled this but nothing has made sense to me so far. I did read somewhere that putting in `'soap_version'=>'SOAP_1_2'` but hasn't made any difference.

The soap service works fine when using the WcfTestClient software so it must be something wrong with how I'm doing the PHP.

**UPDATE**
Below is the Soap request header

```
Accept:text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8
Accept-Charset:ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.3
Accept-Encoding:gzip,deflate,sdch
Accept-Language:en-GB,en;q=0.8
Cache-Control:max-age=0
Connection:keep-alive
Cookie:PHPSESSID=o9iaupn13vq7p812t4bhos97p6; user=cboard
Host:localhost
User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.11 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/23.0.1271.64 Safari/537.11
```

Below is the response header

```
Content-Length:142
Content-Type:text/plain
Date:Fri, 23 Nov 2012 21:35:55 GMT
Server:Microsoft-IIS/7.5
X-Powered-By:PHP/5.3.13
X-Powered-By:ASP.NET
```

Comment: can you check this one http://stackoverflow.com/a/5409465/630316

Comment: Thanks, I did see this but didn't make much sense of how it could be fixed, especially as it wasn't an accepted answer

Comment: add `header('Content-Type: text/plain');` above `$client` `SOAP object`

Comment: @Rafee, I did try that but get the same thing, I also tried, adding header(`Content-type: application/soap+xml`) but it instead downloads the file

Comment: are you using `XAMPP` and what is the environment ?

Comment: No not using XAMPP, its a console application which hosts the wcf library and php is accessible using IIS 7 on Windows 7

Comment: @Rafee I've added the soap request and response headers as requested

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is that the response coming back is an error page (text/plain) rather than a web service response (application/xml)

To try and fix it first find out what the error is. Use Wire Shark (or something similar) to see what is being sent back.

If the information in the error is not enough to find the problem. Use Wire Shark again and capture the request from your php client and from the WCF Test client, then compare the two.

Comment: The problem is I can't do a LAN trace using wireshark as its being developed on my local computer and Wireshark cannot capture localhost traffic on Windows

Comment: Try RawCap, that should be able to sniff localhost traffic

Answer (score 0):

Thanks everyone for your help and suggestions, by some miracle I managed to find out what the problem is.

I needed to change the binding from `wsHttpBinding` to `basicHttpBinding` and now it is accessible via PHP.