# PHP SoapClient Cannot process the message because the content type 'text/xml;

Tags: php, xml, web-services, soap, soap-client

I cannot connect to webservice and send/receive data

**Error**

> HTTP,Cannot process the message because the content type 'text/xml;
>   charset=utf-8' was not the expected type 'application/soap+xml;
>   charset=utf-8'.

**Code**

```
    $parameters = [
        'UserName' => 12324,
        'Password' => 432123,
        'Bill_Id' => 153585611140,
        'Payment_Id' => 8560103,
    ];

    $url="https://bill.samanepay.com/CheckBill/BillStateService.svc?wsdl";
    $method = "VerifyBillPaymentWithAddData";

    $client = new SoapClient($url);

    try{

        $info = $client->__call($method, array($parameters));

    }catch (SoapFault $fault){  

        die($fault->faultcode.','.$fault->faultstring);

    }
```

`Notice` : not work Soap version 1,1 and other resolve sample for this error in stackoverflow.

Answer (score 5):

You could try

```
$url = "https://bill.samanepay.com/CheckBill/BillStateService.svc?wsdl";

try {
    $client = new SoapClient($url, [
        "soap_version" => SOAP_1_2, // SOAP_1_1
        'cache_wsdl' => WSDL_CACHE_NONE, // WSDL_CACHE_MEMORY
        'trace' => 1,
        'exception' => 1,
        'keep_alive' => false,
        'connection_timeout' => 500000
    ]);
    print_r($client->__getFunctions());
} catch (SOAPFault $f) {
    error_log('ERROR => '.$f);
}
```

to verify that your method name is correct.

There you can see the method

```
VerifyBillPaymentWithAddDataResponse VerifyBillPaymentWithAddData(VerifyBillPaymentWithAddData $parameters)
```

Next is to check the Type `VerifyBillPaymentWithAddData` and if the parameter can be an array.
Also you could test to call the method via

```
$client->VerifyBillPaymentWithAddData([
    'UserName' => 12324,
    'Password' => 432123,
    'Bill_Id' => 153585611140,
    'Payment_Id' => 8560103,
]);
```

or yours except the additional array

```
$info = $client->__call($method, $parameters);
```

EDIT:
Assuming to https://stackoverflow.com/a/5409465/1152471 the error could be on the server side, because the server sends an header back that is not compatible with SOAP 1.2 standard.

Maybe you have to use an third party library or even simple sockets to get it working.

Answer (score 0):

Just use the following function. Have fun!

```
function WebServices($function, $parameters){
        
    $username = '***';
    $password = '***';

    $url = "http://*.*.*.*/*/*/*WebService.svc?wsdl";
    $service_url = 'http://*.*.*.*/*/*/*WebService.svc';
    

    
    $client = new SoapClient($url, [
        "soap_version" => SOAP_1_2,
        "UserName"=>$username, 
        "Password"=>$password,
        "SOAPAction"=>"http://tempuri.org/I*WebService/$function",
        'cache_wsdl' => WSDL_CACHE_NONE, // WSDL_CACHE_MEMORY
        'trace' => 1,
        'exception' => 1,
        'keep_alive' => false,
        'connection_timeout' => 500000
    ]);
    $action = new \SoapHeader('http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing', 'Action', "http://tempuri.org/I*WebService/$function");
    $to = new \SoapHeader('http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing', 'To', $service_url);
    $client->__setSoapHeaders([$action, $to]);
    try{
        return $client->__call($function, $parameters);  
    } catch(SoapFault $e){
        return $e->getMessage();
    }
}
```

Comment: Add some explanation to your answer