# The SOAP action specified on the message, '', does not match the HTTP SOAP Action,

Tags: php, web-services, soap

I am trying to connect my script to the SOAP client. But when I try to do it throws the mentioned error. When I tried to get the function with 
`$client->__getFunctions()`. It shows all the function. when I try to call them it ends in fatal error.

```
$client = new SoapClient("http://bsestarmfdemo.bseindia.com/MFOrderEntry/MFOrder.svc?singleWsdl",array(
    'soap_version' => SOAP_1_2, // !!!!!!!
));
var_dump($client->__getFunctions()); 
//var_dump($client->__getTypes());

$login_params = array(
    'UserId' => 123456,
    'Password' => 123456,
    'PassKey' => 1234569870,

  );

//$response = $client->getPassword($login_params);
$response = $client->__soapCall('getPassword', array($login_params));
dd($response);
```

if i change the SOAP version to 1.1 i get another error *Cannot process the message because the content type 'text/xml; charset=utf-8' was not the expected type 'application/soap+xml; charset=utf-8'.* Would be great if i come to know what i am missing here.

Comment: Did you ever find the solution? We're running into the same problem.

Comment: yes i did find a work around. The issue in my case was it expects ws-addressing which is not sent in my case. Have a look at it. @ReSpawN. There can be also mismatch in soap version.

Comment: @NaveenKumar can you please post the solution. we are actually facing the same issue.

Comment: @NaveenKumar can u please post the solution , actually i m also facing same issue. and i too want data from bsestar

Comment: @Wocugon can you also post , if you have found the solution because i need it urgently. please help me out guys.

Comment: @shashikantkuswaha there are some more additional parameters required other than soap_version. this might help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45320590/php-soapclient-cannot-process-the-message-because-the-content-type-text-xml?rq=1
if not maybe try some other sample code on google.

Answer (score 1):

To address the reply made by @Naveen Kumar: this was my solution.

```
// Apply WSA headers
$action = new \SoapHeader('http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing', 'Action', self::ACTION_PREFIX.$this->action);
$to = new \SoapHeader('http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing', 'To', $this->endpoint);
$this->client()->__setSoapHeaders([$action, $to]);
```

In the end, `$this->client` simply returns an instance of `\SoapClient` and the action contains the full URL to the method. Naturally, the `To` portion is optional, but in my case it obviously points towards the endpoint specified in the `.wsdl` file.